# Sorting a JSON object excluding an item

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

I have a JSON object like follows:

```
[
    {"AT&T" : "Blocked"},
    {"All" : "Targeted"},
    {"Verizon" : "Blocked"},
    {"Sprint" : "Blocked"}
]
```

Which I sort alphabetically using the following function:

```
sortByKey : function(array, key) {
        return array.sort(function(a, b) {
            var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
            return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
        });
    },
```

This works fine. What I want to do is EXCLUDE {"All" : "Targeted"} from sorting and always have it as the first element of the JSON object like so:

```
[
   {"All" : "Targeted"},
   {"AT&T" : "Blocked"},
   {"Sprint" : "Blocked"}
   {"Verizon" : "Blocked"}, 
]
```

Could anybody give me a hint of on how can this be achieved? Basically I'll need a way to exclude any item from the JSON object from sorting and set it as the first element of the object.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you can sort it and then move the item. Or remove it first, sort, and re-add it.

Comment: I'm not sure that `sortByKey` works as you think. None of your objects have the same key, so you can't sort by it. You'll end up sorting "undefined" against "undefined". If they're ending up sorted, it's by luck. Regardless, as @GolezTrol hinted, rather than trying to modify your sort function to respect "All", I'd go down the route of sorting it normally and moving it after, or removing it first and pinning it after, *or* not even having it in the list in the first place, and adding it after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to exclude a value, eg keep it at the top of the sort, whenever your sort function encounters it always return -1 if its the first argument or 1 if its the second

```
//Keep 2 at the front
[1,254,6,2,62].sort(function(a,b){
  if(a == 2) return -1; else if(b == 2) return 1;
  return a-b;
});

[2, 1, 6, 62, 254]

//Keep 2 at the back
[1,254,6,2,62].sort(function(a,b){
  if(a == 2) return 1; else if(b == 2) return -1;
  return a-b;
});

[1, 6, 62, 254, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `arr` is your array the easiest way is to take the first element using [`shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) which will leave you the remaining elements in the array to loop over, after which you can just prepend the first element back to the beginning of the array using [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift):

```
var first = arr.shift();

// arr now contains just the other elements
// do your sorting

arr.unshift(first);
```

Or, if the 'All' element isn't at the beginning of the array, using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)/[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to grab the index of 'All', then use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to get the new array, and then use `unshift` to add the element back.

```
var index = arr.map(function(el, i) {
  if (Object.keys(el)[0] === 'All') { return i; }
}).filter(Number)[0];

var first = arr.splice(index, 1)[0];

// arr now contains just the other elements
// do your sorting

arr.unshift(first);
```

Comment: @Matt, cheers. Took a moment but found a decent solution to that problem.

Comment: Beware that `splice()` returns an *array* of the elements removed, so you need `var first = arr.splice(index, 1)[0]`. There are times where a simple `for (;;)` loop might be more suitable than the "posh" *new* array methods; this might be one of them though (http://jsfiddle.net/JGeey/)